# Copying and pasting from MS Project to MS Excel

Tags: vba, excel

This copies data from a project into Excel to be calculated into a final report. The code runs pretty slowly at this point and I would like it to be a little bit faster. Are there any blatant coding mishaps that are slowing the calculations down?

```
Sub Update_Schedule()
Dim appProj As MSProject.Application
Dim aProg As MSProject.Project
Dim sel As MSProject.Selection
Dim ts As Tasks
Dim t As Task
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet


Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Clear current contents

Set ws2 = Worksheets("Final Report")

Set ws = Worksheets("Master")
Set rng = ws.Range("A:F")
rng.ClearContents
Set ws = Worksheets("Resource List")
Set rng = ws.Range("A:B")
rng.ClearContents

'Open the Project file when it asks to open resource pool, press yes

Set appProj = CreateObject("Msproject.Application")

appProj.DisplayAlerts = False

appProj.FileOpen "File_1.mpp" 'also opens file 2

Set aProg = appProj.Projects("File_1.mpp")

appProj.Visible = True

WindowActivate WindowName:=aProg

'Copy the project columns and paste into Excel

Set ts = aProg.Tasks
SelectTaskColumn Column:="Name"
OutlineShowAllTasks
OutlineShowAllTasks
EditCopy
Set ws = Worksheets("Master")
Set rng = ws.Range("A:A")
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=rng
SelectTaskColumn Column:="Duration"
EditCopy
Set rng = ws.Range("B:B")
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=rng
SelectTaskColumn Column:="Start"
EditCopy
Set rng = ws.Range("C:C")
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=rng
SelectTaskColumn Column:="Finish"
EditCopy
Set rng = ws.Range("D:D")
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=rng
SelectTaskColumn Column:="Resource Names"
EditCopy
Set rng = ws.Range("E:E")
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=rng
SelectTaskColumn Column:="Project"
EditCopy
Set rng = ws.Range("F:F")
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=rng
WindowActivate WindowName:="\\File_2.mpp"
SelectResourceColumn Column:="Name"
EditCopy
Set ws = Worksheets("Resource List")
Set rng = ws.Range("A:A")
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=rng
SelectResourceColumn Column:="Category"
EditCopy
Set rng = ws.Range("B:B")
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=rng

'Populates formula in Master sheet
Application.Visible = True

Set ws = Worksheets("Master")
Set rng = ws.Range("G2")
Set rng2 = ws.Range("G2:G9223")
rng.AutoFill Destination:=rng2, Type:=xlFillDefault
Set rng = ws.Range("H2")
Set rng2 = ws.Range("H2:H9223")
rng.AutoFill Destination:=rng2, Type:=xlFillDefault

Calculate

ws2.Visible = True

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
appProj.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Opening up MS Project, and opening up a file in it will be slow. If that's the slow part, it might be ard to speed it up. I would suggest adding a [Debug.Print](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa716276(v=VS.60).aspx) with the timestemp after each line to see which ones are slow.

Comment: I've done some debugging and the slowest part is actually the part under the comment "populates formula in master sheet." It may just be that filling in the formula takes awhile.

Comment: Do you always have data down to row 9,223? If you might have much less data, you might see significant improvement if you figure out how much data you actually have and then fill down that number of rows.

Comment: I usually don't have data that far down. Is there a good way to fill to just the last cell?

Comment: If you search on [so] you will find examples of how to find the last row/cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My earlier comment was: Do you always have data down to row 9,223? If you might have much less data, you might see significant improvement if you figure out how much data you actually have and then fill down that number of rows.

Here is an example of code:

```
Set ws = Worksheets("Master")
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = LastRowNum(ws.Name, "A")
Set rng = ws.Range("G2")
Set rng2 = ws.Range("G2:G" & lastRow)
rng.AutoFill Destination:=rng2, Type:=xlFillDefault
Set rng = ws.Range("H2")
Set rng2 = ws.Range("H2:H" & lastRow)
rng.AutoFill Destination:=rng2, Type:=xlFillDefault

...
End Sub

Function LastRowNum(sheetName As String, columnLetter As String) As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)
        LastRowNum = .Range(columnLetter & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, I've had some success with code similar to this.

Comment: If you are happy with one of the answers, please remember to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

A few things here:

- Read [this](https://www.soa.org/News-and-Publications/Newsletters/Compact/2012/january/com-2012-iss42-roper.aspx). Its lists things to do when copying large amounts of data
- Did you set `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`? Your manually calling Calculate, but you never turn off autocalcualtion.
- Did you set `Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE`? That can speed things up.

Comment: Auto calculation is turned off in the excel file. Am I correct in thinking that it will remain off while running the macro?

Comment: Yes, it will be off. you Could, to be safe, save the value of Application.Calcualtion to a variable, then turn it off then restore it to the old value. What about toggling screen updating?